# How to add asterisk to a list of filenames and then make it a line using Notepad++

Tags: line, space

I have a list of file names (about 4000).

For example:

```
A-67569
H-67985
J-87657
K-85897
...
```

I need to put an asterisk before and after each file name. And then make it a line format.

Example:

```
*A-67569* *H-67985* *J-87657* *K-85897* so on...
```

Note that there is a space between filenames.

Forgot to mention, I'm trying to do this with `Notepad++`

How can I do it?

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: What language are you going to use?

Comment: low quality question, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly

Comment: Hello. This is not for any programming. I need to make this string in order to use it on Total Commander to search 4000 file names in 50000 folders. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

C# example for list to string plus edits

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "A - 67569"), "H-67985", "J-87657", "K-85897"};
string outString = "";
foreach(string item in list)
{
outString += "*" + item + "* ";
}
```

content of outstring: `*A - 67569* *H-67985* *J-87657* *K-85897*`

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to use Notepad++. How can I do this? I'm not a programmer either. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Replace` of your `Notedad++` (`Search > Replace..`)

1. Select `Extended (\n \r \t \0 \x...)` on the bottom of the `Replace` window
2. In the field `Find what` write '\r\n' and in the field `Replace with` write `* *`
3. `Replace all`

Note, that you should manually place the single asterisk before the first and after the last words.

If this won't work, in step 2. instead of `\r\n` try to use only `\n` or `\r`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regular expression** in the search Mode.

**Find what:**

```
(\S+)(\R|$)
```

**Replace with:**

```
*$1
```

**Note the space after de number one**

For the archive

```
A-67569
H-67985
J-87657
K-85897
```

Output:

```
*A-67569 *H-67985 *J-87657 *K-85897
```

[image: Replace]

Explication of regex:

**(\S+)** Mean find one or more caracters is not a blank.

**(\R|$)** Mean find any end of line or end of file

**(\S+)(\R|$)** Mean find any gorup of caracters not blank ho end with  end of line or end of file.

Explication of **Replace  with**
When you use the **$** simpbol, you are using a reference to the groups finded, **$1** is the first group, in this case the group **(\S+)**.